# Explode multiple columns from nested JSON but it is giving extra records

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nested

I have a JSON document like below:

```json
 {
    "Data": [{
            "Code": "ABC",
            "ID": 123456,
            "Type": "Yes",
            "Geo": "East"
        }, {
            "Code": "XYZ",
            "ID": 987654,
            "Type": "No",
            "Geo": "West"
        }],
    "Total": 2,
    "AggregateResults": null,
    "Errors": null
 }
```

My PySpark sample code:

```
getjsonresponsedata=json.dumps(getjsondata)
jsonDataList.append(getjsonresponsedata)

jsonRDD = sc.parallelize(jsonDataList)
df_Json=spark.read.json(jsonRDD)

display(df_Json.withColumn("Code",explode(col("Data.Code"))).withColumn("ID",explode(col("Data.ID"))).select('Code','ID'))
```

When I explode the JSON then I get below records (it looks like cross join)

```text
Code  ID
ABC   123456
ABC   987654
XYZ   123456
XYZ   987654
```

But I expect the records like below:

```text
Code  ID
ABC   123456
XYZ   987654
```

Could you please help me on how to get the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to explode `Data` column, then you can select fields from the resulting struct column (`Code`, `Id`...). What duplicates the rows here is that you're exploding 2 arrays `Data.Code` and `Data.Id`.

Try this instead:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df_Json.withColumn("Data", F.explode("Data")).select("Data.Code", "Data.Id").show()

#+----+------+
#|Code|    Id|
#+----+------+
#| ABC|123456|
#| XYZ|987654|
#+----+------+
```

Or using [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#inline) function directly on `Data` array:

```
df_Json.selectExpr("inline(Data)").show()

#+----+----+------+----+
#|Code| Geo|    ID|Type|
#+----+----+------+----+
#| ABC|East|123456| Yes|
#| XYZ|West|987654|  No|
#+----+----+------+----+
```